# return success function if any of one promise will be resolved

Tags: jquery

I'm learning to use Promises. And the following things I know:

```
$.when(promise1,promise2,promise3).then(doneCallback, failCallback);
```

With the `.when()` method, when all the promises are resolved then `doneCallback` will return and when any of the promises are rejected then `failCallback` will return.

But I want to know if there is any way to do if any one of the promise is resolved while other promises may be rejected then `doneCallback` would return.

I don't know if this applies to real-world use case. But I just want to know if there is a way - How to do?

Answer (score 1):

you may track every single promise status and if at least one promise was resolved set a boolean variable to true. If the the value of the boolean is true then resolve a master deferred object, otherwise reject it e.g.

```
function checkPromises() {
    var onePromisesResolved = false;
    var checkedPromises = 0;
    var dfd = $.Deferred();


    var markPromise = function() {
        checkedPromises++;
        if (checkedPromises === 3) {
            if (onePromisesResolved) {
                dfd.resolve();
            }
            else {
                dfd.reject();
            }
        }
    }  
    var checkResolved = function() {
       onePromisesResolved = onePromisesResolved || true; 
       markPromise();
    }
    var checkFailed = function() {
       onePromisesResolved = onePromisesResolved || false; 
       markPromise();
    }

    $.when(promise1).then(checkResolved, checkFailed);
    $.when(promise2).then(checkResolved, checkFailed);
    $.when(promise3).then(checkResolved, checkFailed);

    return dfd.promise();
};  

$.when(checkPromises).then(doneCallback, failCallback)
```

if at least one promise was resolved then the boolean variable is true (it is the result of an expression of an `or` concatenation)

Comment: `onePromisesResolved` will always be `false` since the callbacks are asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to take a different approach if you need to check for one-of promise type. Jquery $.when() function takes a list of promises, execute them one after another, and when all are done calls the success handler. But on the first promise that fail, the control goes immediately to the then() part. That is its standard behavior.
If you expected that one promise can be rejected and other promise compensate for it, then you need create a separate promise for that case, and list it in your $.when(..) call.
See below code to illustrate above approach.

```js
  
    
    var firstUrl = 'http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/';
    var secondUrl = 'http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/';
    
    function documentReady() {
      var deferredReady = $.Deferred();
      $(document).ready(function() {
          deferredReady.resolve();
        });
      return deferredReady.promise();
    }
    
    function firstCompleted(url1, url2) {
      var deferredFirst = $.Deferred();
      
      $.get(url1, function(data, status) {
        if ('success' == status) {
          deferredFirst.resolve(url1);
        }
      });
      
      $.get(url2, function(data, status) {
        if ('success' == status) {
          deferredFirst.resolve(url2);
        }
      });
      
      return deferredFirst.promise();
    }
    
    $.when (documentReady(), firstCompleted(firstUrl, secondUrl) ).then(
      function (readyData, firstData) {
        $('#winner').html("The winner is " + firstData);
    });
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div id="winner"></div>
```

The straight answer to your question is No, you can not have one of the promises fail and still call the successHandler.

Comment: Run the snippet few times to see asynchronous calls result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a dedicated Promises Library like Bluebird which supports `some()` and `any()`

https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#someint-count---promise

this might work

```
function anyPromise() {
    var def = $.Deferred(),
        rejectCount = 0;

    $.each(arguments, function (i, promise) {
        promise.then(function (value) {
            if (def.state() === 'pending')
                def.resolve(value);
        }, function (value) {
            rejectCount++;
            if (rejectCount === arguments.length)
                def.reject(value);
        });
    });

    return def.promise();
}

anyPromise(promise1, promise2, promise3).then(doneCallback, failCallback);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Isn't there any way to do without including other library?

Comment: What's the difference between some() and any() ?

Comment: well, ES6 native promises also have [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race), but it works a bit differently, if a promise is rejected first, everything is rejected.

Comment: Using what you have now you'd need a bit more lines of code but it's doable

Comment: @BhojendraNepal `some` accepts a number, while `any` is like calling `some` with 1

Answer (score 0):

Edit, Updated

Try utilizing [deferred.always()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/)

```
(function ($) {
    $.whenAt = whenAt;   
    function whenAt() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments[0]) // promises
            // resolve `whenAt` at `resolveAt` : `Number` ,
            // of resolved `args` promises
            , resolveAt = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments[1]) 
            , deferred = new $.Deferred()
            , promises = p = {
                "resolved": [],
                "rejected": []
            }
            , doneCallback = function (res, state) {
                promises[state].push(res);
                // console.log(res, promises, $.now());
                // strict comparison `===` may not be accurate
                // due to asynchronous returned promise values ,
                // return true if resolved length `>=` resolveAt
                return (p.resolved.length >= resolveAt) 
                        ? deferred.resolve(promises) : res
            }, failCallback = function (res, state) {
                promises[state].push(res);
                // console.log(res, promises, $.now());
                return (p.resolved.length + p.rejected.length) === args.length 
                ? deferred.resolve(promises) : res
            };
        $.map(args, function (promise, index) {
            return promise.always(function (data) {
                var state = this.state();
                return state === "resolved" ? doneCallback.call(this, {
                    index: index, // log `index` of `resolved`
                    data: data 
                }, state) : failCallback.call(this, {
                    index: index, // log `index` of `rejected`
                    data: data
                }, state)
            })
        });
        return deferred.promise()
    };
}(jQuery));
```

---

```
// e.g.,
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

, dfd = function (i) {
            return new $.Deferred(function (d) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    // throw `error` if `i` === 2
                    if (i === 2) d.reject(new Error("error").message)
                    else d.resolve(i)
                }, 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000));
            }).promise()
         }

, results = $("#results");

$.whenAt([
    dfd(1)
    , dfd(2)
    , dfd(3)
    , dfd(4)
    , dfd(5)
    , $.Deferred(function (d) {
          setTimeout(function () {
              // throw `error`
              d.reject(new Error("error").message)
          }, 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000));
          return d.promise()
      })
], 1) // `1` : `resolveAt`
.then(function (data) {
    results.append("\npromises:\r\n" + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    console.log(data.resolved[0]); // first resolved promise
});
```

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

,
dfd = function (i) {
    return new $.Deferred(function (d) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (i === 2) d.reject(new Error("error").message)
            else d.resolve(i)
        }, 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000));
    }).promise()
}, results = $("#results");

(function ($) {
$.whenAt = whenAt;

function whenAt() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments[0]),
        resolveAt = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments[1]);
        var deferred = new $.Deferred(),
        promises = p = {
            "resolved": [],
            "rejected": []
        }, doneCallback = function (res, state) {
            promises[state].push(res);
            console.log(res, promises, $.now());
            return (p.resolved.length >= resolveAt) 
                    ? deferred.resolve(promises) : res
        }, failCallback = function (res, state) {
            promises[state].push(res);
            console.log(res, promises, $.now());
            return (p.resolved.length + p.rejected.length) === args.length 
            ? deferred.resolve(promises) : res
        };
    $.map(args, function (promise, index) {
        return promise.always(function (data) {
            var state = this.state();
            return state === "resolved" ? doneCallback.call(this, {
                index: index,
                data: data
            }, state) : failCallback.call(this, {
                index: index,
                data: data
            }, state)
        })
    });
    return deferred.promise()
};
}(jQuery));

$.whenAt([
dfd(1), dfd(2), dfd(3), dfd(4), dfd(5), $.Deferred(function (d) {
setTimeout(function () {
    d.reject(new Error("error").message)
}, 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000));
return d.promise()
})], 1)
.then(function (data) {
results.append("\nresolvedAt:\r\n" + JSON.stringify(data.resolved, null, 4));
console.log("resolvedAt:", data.resolved[0])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="results"></pre>
```